# Unable to boot simulator XCode 8

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8

I have tried all the solutions which found on stack overflow, but still not able to resolve it. Somehow its not open the simulator and gives me error "unable to boot simulator".

I have reinstall 2 times xcode and also remove all simulator and add again. also change "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" to ZZ but no solution.

Please help me, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/launchd-sim-crashing-could-not-create-temporary-state-directory regarding data you can collect to help further triage the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try to turn off System Integrity Protection http://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away - it helped me.

Comment: This is only a temporary fix. Later I plan to upgrade OS X to macOS Sierra

Comment: I *HIGHLY* doubt this is a solution.  There is nothing in the simulator that should interact negatively with SIP.  The thing that likely helped in that link was just rebooting.

Comment: @AntonNebylitsa  fixed it for me - thanks.  also, stackoverflow.com/questions/40111984 describes my issue as well with coretelephony error at startup

Comment: @AntonNebylitsa how you even figured out this issue is related to SIP? It's amazing.

Comment: Related post on Apple developer forum: [Link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/189283)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error message was actually "Unable to boot the Simulator.", this error indicates an error starting up launchd_sim when booting the simulated device.  In and of itself, it does not indicate the actual cause.  You can look in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log for more information about the error (including the error reason).

Possible causes:

1. On OSX 10.9 and earlier, DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES could be set by 3rd party applications.  On later versions, invalid DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES are ignored instead of resulting in an error.
2. Usage of older simulator runtime DLC with Xcode 7 betas.  Newer versions of Xcode ignore these older DLC.

If you need additional help, please provide that additional datum.

Also see my answer in the related question: Please see my answer on [launchd_sim crashing: could not create temporary state directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/launchd-sim-crashing-could-not-create-temporary-state-directory) regarding data you can collect to help further triage the problem.

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.0 and simulator iPhone 5SE iOS 10.0 . When I try to run, it always shows me the same message. I have tried with deleting Xcode and reinstalling it. But it didn't work.

Comment: @MilanKamilya If you want further help, you need to provide the information requested.  Look in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log for more information about the error (including the error reason).

Comment: Sorry, I have upgraded to Mac 10.12 Sierra. It resolved all issues.

Comment: I suspect you may have done something to mess up /tmp or /private/tmp and the upgrade fixed your corrupted state.  That seems to be what someone in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/xcode-8-simulator-crashing/40266748#40266748 recently encountered.  Given the recent noise, I wonder if some 3rd party installer is messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

**Problems**:

As I also faced the same problem as below..

--"Unable to boot simulator"
--Storyboard designs/views completely invisible and showing only blue lines.
--CoreTelephony Trace File Error ... failed to create \tmp

**Solutions**

Don't do any SIP (Disable/Enable)settings its just temp solutions & it may harms to other applications in the mac as well as may affecting on secure data in the mac.
Best way to do upgrade your iMac to macOS "Sierra". It will solve all your problems.

Finally I am able to work on my project by solving above strange problems.

Happy coding.. happy Development...!!!

Comment: Please don't upgrade without first filing a radar with relavant details, so we can try to figure out why your system got into this bad state in the first place.  See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/launchd-sim-crashing-could-not-create-temporary-state-directory