# Unable to boot the IOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

When I'm running project build is succeeded, but simulator is not loading saying message "Unable to boot the simulator". Im only able to test in real device.

Please help me .

Thank you....

Comment: What is the target iOS version and what version of iOS is your simulator?

Comment: In all Simulators Im getting same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error opening iOS Simulator with iOS 8 beta version: "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim)

Comment: Tried the same, but same error, Uninstalled Xcode also and installed again not worked

Comment: Your error is: Oct 18 20:05:05  CoreSimulatorService[1546] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.}

Comment: Given that, can you please take a sysdiagnose *immediately* after trying to boot the simulator.  If you wait for that dialog, you waited too log.  Do it *immediately* after booting the sim.  Then file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com with that sysdiagnose attached, so I can take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: if you got solution please share it with us. because i am also facing same problem

Comment: SS, if you have a similar *symptom*, you need to provide the requested data to determine if you actually have the same *problem*.  Don't assume that having the same symptom means you have the same problem.  Please provide the exact error message from ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimualtor/CoreSimualtor.log.  If you have the same error as seen in siva's case (launchd failed to respond), then take a sysdiagnose and file a radar as I mentioned above, so I can triage your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40109077/2086808, This solved my problem but it seems temporary.... . Not sure will it effect any other things

Comment: Please file a radar with a sysdiagnose taken immediately after attempting to boot.

Comment: Please see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/launchd-sim-crashing-could-not-create-temporary-state-directory regarding data you can collect to help further triage the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what exactly is the problem. But there are only 3 possibilities that I can think of:

1. the iOS image that simulator tries to load is corrupted/not
   downloaded properly.
2. You are using a CPU architecture that is not supported by iOS simulator.
3. File permission issues. You are running XCode from a location or by a user that doesn't give you enough access to load the iOS images.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem at the time of the original post. Everything was working fine a day before, running OS X 10.11.6, with both XCode 7.1.1 & XCode 8 installations. Tried everything from rebooting, cleaning, etc. to reinstalling XCode without any success.

In my case, permissions for "private/tmp" mysteriously changed.

1. check .../Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for crashes of "launchd_sim" and possible hints
2. open terminal and run "sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /". If it says something about "private/tmp", you're likely having the same issue.
3. either try to repair the permissions yourself ( it's a pain with El Capitan ), or run a OS X update if you haven't. The later did the trick for me...

Hope it solves your problem as well.

Comment: how to repair  the permissions for "private/tmp" any recommended solution please elaborate your solution. i have same problem. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird one, but updating to macOS Sierra seems to solve it.

Comment: have you know root cause of this problem. because i am facing same problem.please give more info about it,is changing os is fine for this solution

Comment: I don't know what causes the issue, but one of my work mates had the exact same problem yesterday and some extra too (he couldn't even make a .zip archive) and after trying various stuff for the first part of the day, he updated to Sierra and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest simulator (Preference - Components), after installed, run again.