# Xcode 8.1 GM crashed when I try to open .SKS files

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode8, macos-sierra

I've an **iMac 14,2** Late 2013 (i7) with a nVidia **GTX 970** third part **GPU**. All stuff works well until these days with the appearance of the  issue described in title.
I've the same issue with the follow configuration:

- Sierra **10.12.0** GM2 build **16A323**
- **Nvidia** Web Driver **367.15.10.05f01** for build **16A323**
- Xcode 8.0 GM **8A218a**

Today I've installed the new Sierra update and Xcode **GM** version, but I've the same issue:

- Sierra **10.12.1** update build **16B2555**
- Nvidia Web Driver **367.15.10.05f01** for build **16B2555**
- Xcode 8.1 GM **8T61a**

I waited for the release of these new versions to see if the problem was solved but without success.

Another strange problem that **seems related to the use of the third part GPU** is the *Xcode - Open Developer Tools - Instruments*: everytime I try to launch an instrument **I've a transparent empty window**.

Any help or idea to solve this issue is appreciated.

**P.S.** *This issue NOT happened when I use El Capitan v10.11.6, BUT with this OS version and XCode 8 happen another issue related to simulators. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40103415/1894067) for details..I wanted to destroy my iMac.*

**Update (Swift 4)**: with High Sierra 10.13.1 and Xcode 9.2(9c40b) finally this problem is totally solved.

Comment: Ugh, new things...If I could, I would stay forever on Xcode 7.3.1 & El Capitan lol. Not the first time that Scene Editor crashes though.

Comment: @Whirlwind Me too. This issue involved also instruments and this is very frustrating..unusable

Comment: Switching to .sks files from code, that causes the Scene Editors to open, in all iterations of Xcode 8 (since the first beta), have caused 2 to 5 second delays for me. Nothing like this in Xcode 7.x series. I'm running Nvidia chipped MacBook Pros, but 10.11.6 ... can you roll back to this?

Comment: I've been afraid of Sierra for this and many other reasons, and holding out on upgrading. Thank you for this post. It confirms I might be doing the right thing by waiting. Sorry for your suffering.

Comment: Same problems here (Sierra and Xcode 8.1). I figured that Xcode is crashing when I am trying to duplicate Sprite more than once, or if I am creating two new SK scenes one after another. And also on some other "unknown" occasions.